# Completely wiping all contents and storage in SmartQ T10 tablet. No Recovery, no CWM, no ADB

Tags: factory-reset, device-firmware

I wanna hard reset my SmartQ T10 so memory and internal storage become fully deleted, but my device does not have such option in Settings, nor there is ClockWorkMod Recovery released for it.
I did try:
- Restore firmware.
- Boot pressing volume up, volume down and both (goes to firmware restore).
- ADB: adb reboot recovery (goes to firmware restore too).
- Research at http://www.hard-reset.com/ (no SmartQ models there).
so I was wondering if it exists any generic non-platform-specific trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a real safe and complete wipe, you might want to take a look at [Nuke my Device](http://www.appbrain.com/app/nuke-my-device/com.avengermobile.nukemyphone).

If you're just after a factory-reset, this can be find in *Settings*. But then you shouldn't forget about your other storage (SDcards – internal as well as external ­– are usually not dealt with by a factory-reset, though some ROMs do so).

Comment: Well, I was mostly thinking about some NAND Wipe, Cache Wipe and Dalvik Wipe, like in CWM.
As I wrote, there is no factory-reset option in my Settings. Maybe that is because I have installed an unofficial firmware Android 2.3.4 Beta.

Comment: Maybe – though I've never seen any without that option. As I wrote, the app mentioned should cover that. According to its description, it offers you to safely delete/wipe everything, and then automatically factory-resetting the device as a "finalizer". // All those wipes could be done from a *custom* recovery (which you don't have), but also via ADB/Fastboot commands.

Comment: Another equivalent app free, please?

Comment: I don't know any other (free) app doing the same. Just another paid one for the same price. For partial solutions, see the list [here](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/545282/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have finally found a partial solution. By using these commands via ADB, what can be done by USB cable or Wireless ADB (my case), the contents of the internal filesystem of the tablet seems to have become clean:

```
adb shell  
wipe data
```

I hope this info will help anyone.